# Group and Filter/Search Table with HTML JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to adapt a simple Jquery filter, table search.

The Problem:
when you use the input[text] the JQuery filters the rows, this works well but if you type the date you loose the main and extra info rows and visa-versa.

I can't think of an alternative method or (preferably) a way to group all relevant rows, or .show() those rows.

JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/fidlr/zoLbx1dv/)

CODE:
JQuery

```
$("#searchbox").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#layout tr").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="searchbox">
<table id="layout">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Date a</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>time<br>location a</td>
    <td>main info a</td>
    <td>sponsor a</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">extra info a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Date b</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>time<br>location b</td>
    <td>main infob </td>
    <td>sponsor b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">extra info b</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>time<br>location b2</td>
    <td>main info b2</td>
    <td>sponsor b2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">extra info b2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

More info:
The rows are generated dynamically with php; i've tried grouping rows by classes.

EDIT

**ideal search result examples:**
search [main info a] would also leave [date a] and [extra info a]
search [main info b2] would also leave [date b] and [extra info b2]
search

Comment: are you able to add a class to `<tr/>`'s that contain "extra info" and "date" cells?

Comment: @DacreDenny yes, presuming you mean `<tr>` although when i did that, the Jquery i wrote worked if you was looking for 1 letter, the second letter sent the script unpredictable.